# Working with @2x images and its sizes

Tags: image

I am making an app and have started designing it. I currently have an image for my app icon and its size is 57x57. I was wondering for the retina display (@2x) images, do i have to double the originals size, or whats the deal.

Comment: Googling "icons for retina display" finds plenty of information...

Comment: Have a look at that: http://www.vickiwenderlich.com/2012/09/app-icon-size-reference-chart/.

Comment: I found a Photoshop template which will help with the icon resizing stuff here - http://appicontemplate.com/  Hope this helps!

Comment: Another option with great re-sizable icons is http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Double the size but make sure you set the height/width to what you want in the CSS.

Comment: Yes, but then all the images become pixalated

Comment: You cannot just double the current image size. You must have an original image that is at least double the size of what you are trying to achieve and scale it. If you only make the current image twice as big then, yes, it will be pixilated.

Comment: Okay, do I also have to have @2x images for example UIbuttons ?

Comment: @Carl Any image that you want to display will need to have its resolution doubled. Most times we use SVG whenever possible for buttons and icons. You might google for 'icon fonts', too.